# Using gnome_disks to reduce partition size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I would like to reduce the size of a partition formatted as ext4 from 1000GB to 991 GB. That partition is currently 40% full. (I have a target partition for a backup available, but it is only 991 GB in size. So, I cannot first backup my partition before making any changes.)

If I go to gparted, it reports that the minimum size of the partition is 953356 MiB, but it also reports this as the maximum size. I cannot enter any new size other than 953356.

My question is whether the gnome_disks utility knows how to *safely* reduce the size of a partition so that I do not lose or corrupt any files. If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason to only reduce by 9GBs?  Kind of small to do anything useful.  Need to work on partitions unmounted from a live USB, not from working sysstem.

Comment: Think you mixing up backups with cloning.  Cloning a whole disk/partition usually requires to be done to same size or bigger, backups don't.  Working on partitions can cause data lost, which is why it is recommended to have backups.  Working with the right side(empty) usually does not, left side usually does.

Comment: crip659 My question concerns the use of gnome_disks. Your comments are sidetracking.

Comment: Gnome disks should be safe for your data if you do the resizing from the right side for the small amount you want to do.  Partition has to be unmounted, so resizing has to done from another drive. Booting from Live Ubuntu USB usually recommended.  I like gparted myself and it is included on live USBs.  Ubuntu does not allow partition work from same system.

Comment: @crip659  What do you mean by "...from the right side..."?

Comment: When using gnome disks or gparted, the way partitions are shown on screen.  On left side of screen/picture is the beginning of partition(very dangerous to work on).  The right side of partition will the end and should be empty/free space.  All your data should be in the first 400GBs(~40%) from the beginning(left).

Answer (score -1):

Same for me. i try to resize my linux partition (60Gb) and it says that max is 60Gb and min is 60Gb.

Possible Solutions:

- 1. Do it on a LiveUSB, not in the system.
- 2. Make sure that you don't reached the 4 partitons limit of MBR Partiton schemes (doesn't help if you have an GPT Partiton scheme)

Question: Does your partition has a key icon on it in gparted?
it means that the partiton is in use.
the 1st solution may help you because while booting from an LiveUSB the linux partiton is not used. (and you can resize the linux partiton, even REMOVE it)